# Ucrop activity skips with camera image :Android

Tags: java, android, android-camera, ucrop

I used Ucrop to crop an image from camera, but the activity skips. Here is my MainActivity.java file. I think i'm missing something. My code is little bit longer, please take a look. Thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.sathwik.uploadtrail1;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.yalantis.ucrop.UCrop;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // LogCat tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    // Camera activity request codes
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video
    private Button btnCapturePicture, btnRecordVideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Changing action bar background color

        //getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(R.color.action_bar))));
        btnCapturePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
        btnRecordVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);

        /**
        * Capture image button click event
        */
        btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            captureImage();
         }
        });
        /**
          Record video button click event
         */
        btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // record video
            recordVideo();
            }
            });
        // Checking camera availability
        if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // will close the app if the device does't have camera
        finish();
        }
        }
    /**
      checking device has camera hardware or not
       */
    private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
    if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
    PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
    // this device has a camera
    return true;
    } else {
    // no camera on this device
    return false;
    }
    }
    /**
          * Launching camera app to capture image
          */
    private void captureImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);


    }


    /**
          * Launching camera app to record video
          */
    private void recordVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
        // set video quality
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);// set the image file
        // name
        // start the video capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /** Perform UCrop */
    public void performUcrop(){
        UCrop.of(fileUri, fileUri).start(this);
    }
        /**
              * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
              * app
              */
        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
            // changes
            outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            // get the file url
            fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
        }
        /**
              * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
              * */
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
            // if the result is capturing Image
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    performUcrop();
                    // successfully captured the image
                    // launching upload activity
                    launchUploadActivity(true);
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // user cancelled Image capture
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // video successfully recorded
                    //launching upload activity
                    launchUploadActivity(false);
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // user cancelled recording
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    private void launchUploadActivity(boolean isImage){
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("filePath", fileUri.getPath());
        i.putExtra("isImage", isImage);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
          * Creating file uri to store image/video
          */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /**
          * returning image / video
          */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Oops! Failed create "+ Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator+ "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator+ "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        return mediaFile;
    }

    //Logout function
    private void logout(){
        //Creating an alert dialog to confirm logout
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?");
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        //Getting out sharedpreferences
                        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        //Getting editor
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

                        //Puting the value false for loggedin
                        editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

                        //Putting blank value to email
                        editor.putString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, "");

                        //Saving the sharedpreferences
                        editor.commit();

                        //Starting login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    }
                });

        //Showing the alert dialog
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.menuLogout) {
            logout();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

I added Ucrop libraries in my gradle file. My gradle app module has this

```
compile 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.1-native'
```

Android monitor shows this log

```
07-02 00:42:22.953 1534-2050/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.example.sathwik.uploadtrail1/com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity (has extras)} from uid 10058 on display 0
07-02 00:42:22.954 1534-2050/system_process V/WindowManager: addAppToken: AppWindowToken{2e96b812 token=Token{39e8cb9d ActivityRecord{22ae1a74 u0 com.example.sathwik.uploadtrail1/com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity t29}}} to stack=1 task=29 at 2
07-02 00:42:22.959 1534-1955/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=com.example.sathwik.uploadtrail1/.UploadActivity (has extras)} from uid 10058 on display 0
07-02 00:42:22.962 1534-1955/system_process V/WindowManager: addAppToken: AppWindowToken{278b8499 token=Token{39cc69e0 ActivityRecord{322e0be3 u0 com.example.sathwik.uploadtrail1/.UploadActivity t29}}} to stack=1 task=29 at 3
07-02 00:42:23.578 14053-14053/com.example.sathwik.uploadtrail1 I/Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 00:42:23.945 1534-1836/system_process V/WindowManager: Adding window Window{14ab833f u0 com.example.sathwik.uploadtrail1/com.example.sathwik.uploadtrail1.UploadActivity} at 6 of 11 (after Window{14c5edfe u0 com.android.camera/com.android.camera.Camera})
07-02 00:42:24.332 1534-1563/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.example.sathwik.uploadtrail1/.UploadActivity: +1s293ms
07-02 00:42:24.333 1534-1558/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 2721:com.google.android.gms.unstable/u0a7 (adj 15): empty for 3423s
07-02 00:42:24.333 1534-1558/system_process W/libprocessgroup: failed to open /acct/uid_10007/pid_2721/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
07-02 00:42:25.366 2376-14273/com.google.android.gms W/PlatformStatsUtil: Could not retrieve Usage & Diagnostics setting. Giving up.
07-02 00:42:25.374 1534-1836/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 9541:com.android.calendar/u0a18 (adj 15): empty for 2545s
07-02 00:42:25.374 1534-1836/system_process W/libprocessgroup: failed to open /acct/uid_10018/pid_9541/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

UCrop is working fine, but you are starting it the wrong way, if you specify the same argument for source and destination, the onActivityResult will be called immediately. and obviously with no result, fix:
1. specify different source and destination
UCrop.of(fileUri, dstUri).start(this);
2. add the code to handle the response from uCrop. in my tutorial
https://youtu.be/glwM0cAUV4A, the code in onActivityResult is not perfect but it works.